# Can Windsor inject lists of components?

Tags: castle-windsor

Consider this example:

```
    public class Factory
    {
        private List<ISubFactory> subFactories;

        public Factory(List<ISubFactory> subFactories)
        {
            this.subFactories = subFactories;
        }
    }

    public interface ISubFactory
    {

    }
```

I want Windsor to resolve the Factory class and put all implementers of the ISubFactory interface which are registered in the container (ResolveAll) into the "subFactories" parameter, can Windsor do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it can. But you have to opt in first, by registering ListResolver

```
container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new ListResolver(container.Kernel));
```